# How to compute the top k words

Tags: spark-streaming

I would like to compute the top *k* words in a Spark-Streaming application, with lines of text collected in a time window.

I ended up with the following code:

```
...
val window = stream.window(Seconds(30))

val wc = window
  .flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(w => (w, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)

wc.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  println("---------------------------------------------------")
  rdd.top(10)(Ordering.by(_._2)).zipWithIndex.foreach(println)
})
...
```

It seems to work.

**Problem**:
the top *k* word chart is computed using the `foreachRDD` function that executes a top+print function on each `RDD` returned by `reduceByKey` (the `wc` variable).

It turns out that `reduceByKey` returns a `DStream` with a single `RDD`, so the above code works but the correct behaviour is not guaranteed by the specs.

Am I wrong, and it works in all circumstances ?

Why there is not, in spark-streaming, a way to consider a `DStream` as a single `RDD`, instead of a collection of `RDD` objects, in order to execute more complex transformations ?

What I mean is a function like: `dstream.withUnionRDD(rdd => ...)` that allows you making transformation and actions on a single/union `RDD`. Is there an equivalent way to do such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I completely misunderstood the concept of DStream composed of multiple RDDs. A DStream is made by multiple RDDs, but over time.

In the context of a micro-batch, the DStream is made of the current RDD.

So, the code above always works.